# Data scheme Cassandra using various data types

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, data-modeling

Currently I am developing a solution in the field of time-series data. Within these data we have: an ID, a value and a timestamp.
So here it comes: the value might be of type boolean, float or string. I consider three approaches:

a) For every data type a distinct table, all sensor values of type boolean into a table, all sensor values of type string into another. The obvious disadvantage is that you have to know where to look for a certain sensor.

b) A meta-column describing the data type plus all values of type string. The obvious disadvantage is the data conversion e.g. for calculating the MAX, AVG and so on.

c) Having three columns of different type but only one will be with a value per record. The disadvantage is 500000 sensors firing every 100ms ... plenty of unused space.

As my knowledge is limited any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 500000 sensors firing every 100ms

First thing, is to make sure that you partition properly, to make sure that you don't exceed the limit of 2 billion columns per partition.

```
CREATE TABLE sensorData (
  stationID uuid,
  datebucket text,
  recorded timeuuid,
  intValue bigint,
  strValue text,
  blnValue boolean, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((stationID,datebucket),recorded));
```

With a half-million every 100ms, that's 500 million in a second.  So you'll want to set your `datebucket` to be very granular...down to the second.  Next I'll insert some data:

```
 stationid                            | datebucket          | recorded                             | blnvalue | intvalue | strvalue
--------------------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------+----------+----------
 8b466f1d-8d6b-46fa-9f5b-8c4eb51aa40c | 2015-04-22T14:54:29 | 6338df40-e929-11e4-88c8-21b264d4c94d |     null |       59 |     null
 8b466f1d-8d6b-46fa-9f5b-8c4eb51aa40c | 2015-04-22T14:54:29 | 633e0f60-e929-11e4-88c8-21b264d4c94d |     null |     null |       CD
 8b466f1d-8d6b-46fa-9f5b-8c4eb51aa40c | 2015-04-22T14:54:29 | 6342f160-e929-11e4-88c8-21b264d4c94d |     True |     null |     null
 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f | 2015-04-22T14:56:19 | a48bbdf0-e929-11e4-88c8-21b264d4c94d |    False |     null |     null
```

> ...plenty of unused space.

You might be suprised.  With the *CQL* output of `SELECT *` above, it appears that there are `null` values all over the place.  But watch what happens when we use the `cassandra-cli` tool to view how the data is stored "under the hood:"

```
RowKey: 3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f:2015-04-22T14\:56\:19
=> (name=a48bbdf0-e929-11e4-88c8-21b264d4c94d:, value=, timestamp=1429733297352000)
=> (name=a48bbdf0-e929-11e4-88c8-21b264d4c94d:blnvalue, value=00, timestamp=1429733297352000)
```

As you can see, the data (above) stored for the CQL row where `stationid=3221b1d7-13b4-40d4-b41c-8d885c63494f AND datebucket='2015-04-22T14:56:19'` shows that `blnValue` has a value of `00` (false).  But also notice that `intValue` and `strValue` are not present.  Cassandra doesn't force a `null` value like an RDBMS does.

> The obvious disadvantage is the data conversion e.g. for calculating the MAX, AVG and so on.

Perhaps you already know this, but I did want to mention that Cassandra CQL does not contain definitions for `MAX`, `AVG` or any other data aggregation function.  You'll either need to do that client-side, or implement Apache-Spark to perform OLAP-type queries.

Be sure to read through Patrick McFadin's [Getting Started With Time Series Data Modeling](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/).  It contains good suggestions on how to solve time series problems like this.

Comment: Just realized that I missed your mention of "float."  I used a `bigint` in my example instead, but the principle remains the same.